# iOS/Objective C- null response from NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios

This code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cnn.com"]];

[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *res;
NSError *err;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&res error:&err];
NSString *html  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];

NSLog(@"email adress is %@ and password is %@, response is %@, length is %i", self.boxEmail.text, self.boxPassword.text, html, data.length);
```

Shows null for `html`. What is going wrong?

NSLog'ing `data.description` yields:

```
<3c21444f 43545950 45204854 4d4c3e0a 3c68746d 6c206c61 6e673d22 656e2d55 53223e0a 3c686561 643e0a3c
```

etc.

Comment: Could you NSLog [data description] and error so we can help you solve this one :)

Comment: Have you checked the value of your `err` object after sending the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assume the data will be NUL terminated, therefore you should not call `stringWithUTF8String`. Use the following:

```
NSString *html  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

if you are using ARC or:

```
NSString *html  = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

otherwise.

Comment: And the reason why you were getting `nil` as a result is that NSString encountered invalid UTF-8 data when it walked passed the end of your passed bytes.

Comment: @JesseRusak (+1) I was just looking at my answer wondering whether I should add exactly this comment. Thank you!

Comment: @Wells Not the issue. The issue is using `initWithData:encoding` versus `stringWithUtf8String:`. As far as I know there is no `stringWithData:encoding:` If there is that would be fine too!

Comment: I understand it wasn't the issue but I was curious about the change nonetheless.

Comment: @Wells Apologies if I sounded curt, I was rushing out the door and was trying to reply because I was not sure when I would get back. So it is simply that `NSString` does not have a `stringWithData:encoding:` method so there is no option but to call `alloc` followed by `initWithData:encoding`. I have no idea why Apple provides class method equivalents for only some of the init methods. Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following by copying and pasting your code for html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>CNN.com - Breaking News, U.S., World, Weather, Entertainment &amp; Video News</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="2012-08-08T00:48:58Z"/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800;url=http://www.cnn.com/?refresh=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive"/>
<meta name="description" content="CNN.com delivers the latest breaking news and information on the latest top stories, weather, business, entertainment, politics, and more. For in-depth coverage, CNN.com provides special reports, video, audio, photo galleries, and interactive guides."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="CNN,CNN news,CNN.com,CNN TV,news,news online,breaking news,U.S. news,world news,weather,business,CNN Money,sports,politics,law,technology,entertainment,education,travel,health,special reports,autos,developing story,news video,CNN Intl"/>
<meta name="application-name" content="CNN"/>
<meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Breaking News, U.S., World, Weather, Entertainment and Video News"/>
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=News Pulse;action-uri=http://newspulse.cnn.com/;icon-uri=http://www.cnn.com/favicon.ie9.ico"/>
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=iReport;action-uri=http://ireport.cnn.com;icon-uri=http://ireport.cnn.com/favicon.ico"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="80401312489"/>
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="129343697106537"/>
<link href="http://www.cnn.com/" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="http://www.cnn.com/favicon.ie9.ico" rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="/tools/search/cnncom.xml" rel="search" title="CNN.com" 
.
.
.
```